# try catch does not work for "return Json()" exceptions

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

When the length of characters in json result is large the following exception will be raised:

> Error during serialization or deserialization using the JSON JavaScriptSerializer. The length of the string exceeds the value set on the maxJsonLength property.

The above exception is a server side exception with 500 response code so if we put the source code inside a try catch block, the error should be caught in catch block, but try catch does not work for this scenario.

You could test this problem by following code, please use it inside an asp.net mvc controller:

```
public JsonResult Test()
    {
        try
        {
            var result = "";
            var v1 = new JavaScriptSerializer();

            for (int i = 0; i < (v1.MaxJsonLength / 100) + 10; i++)
            {
                result += "0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789";
            }

            //exception message:
            //Error during serialization or deserialization using the JSON JavaScriptSerializer. The length of the string exceeds the value set on the maxJsonLength property.
            return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        catch
        {
            //when exception is raised the catch will not be called

            return null;
        }


    }
```

Comment: I would guess that the response headers have already been written by the time the exception occurs.

Comment: @AntP This is a server side exception so the catch block should be fired, but it wasn't fired after the error.

Comment: Ali Reza - yes, I understood the question.

Comment: Catch block is not firing as there is no C# exception. I ran your code and it hits the break point after almost 3 minutes from the execution of Action method on the line ' return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);' and a huge data stored in 'result'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I cannot reproduce the error, but anyway what is happening to you is that the `Json` method implementation is already catching the exception internally and converting it to full-blown HTTP 5xx response. There is no exception coming out from the `return Json()` call.

There is no chance for you to catch the exception because... what would you do? Generate an HTTP 5xx response? That is already done for you by the MVC framework.

Comment: what's "full-blown HTTP"?

Comment: It was "full-blown HTTP 5xx response." With that I wanted to say entire HTTP response to which there is nothing to add. That is why you are just returning the `ActionResult` produced by the `Json` method - that method is meant to construct entire HTTP response, including error responses.

Answer (score -2):

Try like this:

```
ActionResult result;
try
        {
            var result = "";
            var v1 = new JavaScriptSerializer();

            for (int i = 0; i < (v1.MaxJsonLength / 100) + 10; i++)
            {
                result += "0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789";
            }

            //exception message:
            //Error during serialization or deserialization using the JSON JavaScriptSerializer. The length of the string exceeds the value set on the maxJsonLength property.
            result= Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        catch
        {
            //when exception is raised the catch will not be called
        }
return result;
```

Comment: I want to return JsonResult.

Comment: This has *identical* behavior to the OP.  (Assuming you also return in the `catch`, as the OP does, otherwise the code doesn't compile.)

Comment: @Servy What does **OP** stand for?